# Installed MacPorts PHP, now cannot interface with MySQL - Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, macos, macports

I had the standard version of PHP which comes bundled with Mac OS X working perfectly, but I wanted to upgrade to the new version so I used [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), and all went well. I then edited my `.conf` file and checked and now my version of PHP is updated to the latest version.

However, upon running a PHP project I'm working on, it now seems I am unable to interface with MySQL which was working with the standard PHP install which came bundled with Mac OS X (note: I originally installed MySQL from their installer from their homepage).

My question is this: Is there a way to get MacPort PHP to work with my old MySQL installation?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the `php5-mysql` package from MacPorts?

The default installation of PHP in MacPorts is relatively minimal, but there are lots of add-on modules available.

Comment: Run `/opt/local/bin/php -i` and see whether it lists the mysql (and mysqli) extensions.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './pdo_mysql.so' - dlopen(./pdo_mysql.so, 9)

Comment: Look for that file in /opt/local/lib/php/extensions (and subdirectories)

Comment: Hi it's there I have: mysql.so - mysqli.so and pdo_mysql.so

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Alnitak in the comments, MacPorts 1.9.2 does not have a "mysql" variant.
There is a way to work around it, nevertheless.

The php5-mysql port has a +mysql5 variant, but there is an even better way to solve to problem.

This is a great blog post http://top-frog.com/2009/08/26/macports-php5-mysql-mysqlnd/
which only states the same phrase that the php5-mysql post-install script does:

`To use mysqlnd with a local MySQL server, edit /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini and set mysql.default_socket, mysqli.default_socket and pdo_mysql.default_socket to /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock`

So if you're using MacOS X Server native MySQL server that socket would be easy to get by running `ps ax | grep mysql`. For me it was `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

And you could of course always change the socket in `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

In a moment of madness I worked it out.

Removed PHP from existence using MacPorts then reinstalled but this time added +mysql to the install.

Once this was done installed php5-mysql using MacPorts also. Then it worked!

Comment: strange - my install of MacPorts (v1.9.2) doesn't have a "+mysql" variant of PHP5.

Comment: you should check my comment out and everything will work out of the box, without having to install variants of ports.

Answer (score 0):

I also went to same problem with mysql and php5 installed. Luckily I am able to fix this by following Vlads advice; in a little different way. Note that  port php5-mysql is NOT REQUIRED

Try `/usr/bin/php -i|grep mysql|grep socket` which results in

```
mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Note that php is pointing to wrong place; it should be `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock`

**Solution:*Create a symlink to correct path***

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s   /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock  /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```